# Automatically enter only running docker container

Tags: bash, docker

In the cloud, I have multiple instances, each running a container with a different random name, e.g.:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        NAMES
5dc97950d924        aws_beanstalk/my-app:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'python    3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          80/tcp, 5000/tcp, 8080/tcp   jolly_galileo
```

To enter them, I type:

```
sudo docker exec -it jolly_galileo /bin/bash
```

Is there a command or can you write a bash script to automatically execute the exec to enter the correct container?

Comment: You want to enter the correct container based on what (image name, ...) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"the correct container"?

To determine what is the "correct" container, your bash script would still need either the id or the name of that container.

For example, I [have a function in my `.bashrc`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/f9890cb6e1ee14842b8be2dd66a754550db793a9/.bash_aliases#L54):

```
deb() { docker exec -u git -it $1 bash; }
```

That way, I would type:

```
deb jolly_galileo
```

(it uses the account git, but you don't have to)

Comment: you will enter the last container started with `docker exec -it $(docker ps -lq) bash` but there is no magic, as VonC said.

Comment: This worked for me! `sudo docker exec -it $(sudo docker ps -lq) bash`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my final solution.  It edits the instance's .bashrc if it hasn't been edited yet, prints out docker ps, defines the dock function, and enters the container.  A user can then type "exit" if they want to access the raw instances, and "exit" again to quit ssh.

```
commands:
  bashrc:
    command:  if ! grep -Fxq "sudo docker ps" /home/ec2-user/.bashrc; then echo -e "dock() { sudo docker exec -it $(sudo docker ps -lq) bash; } \nsudo docker ps\ndock" >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc; fi
```

Comment: Nice feedback in addition of my answer, thank you. +1

Answer (score 1):

As VonC indicated, usually you have to make some shell scripting of your own if you find yourself doing something repetitive. I made a tool myself [here](https://github.com/Pithikos/dockerint) which works if you have Bash 4+.

Install

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Pithikos/dockerint/master/docker_autoenter >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then you can enter a container by simply typing the first letters of the container.

```
$> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               ..
807b1e7eab7e        ubuntu              ..
18e953015fa9        ubuntu              ..
19bd96389d54        ubuntu              ..

$> 18
root@18e953015fa9:/#
```

This works by taking advantage of the function `command_not_found_handle` [introduced in Bash 4](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html). If a command is not found, the script will try and see if what you typed is a container and if it is, it will run `docker exec <container> bash`.